# Is there WebGL 2.0 support in AirConsole?

Tags: unity-webgl, webgl2, airconsole

Trying to figure out if Unity's LWRP could run in AirConsole build.
Apparently LWRP is supported in WebGL2 builds, so the question is - does AirConsole themselves fully support it? If not fully - what features are and what are not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very familiar with Unity nor LWRP, but to clarify:

**AirConsole and it's games always run in a browser** (except on AndroidTV where it may run as a native game). In the end AirConsole is "just" a website or Javascript API. Consequently if the browser supports WebGL 2.0, then it also works with AirConsole.

However, Web GL 2 support seems to be missing on e.g. Safari, which is one of the  platforms supported by AirConsole. A game should run on all major browsers.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl2

I hope this explanation helps you.

Comment: This does not answer the question though. AirConsole is a downloadable app, so in essence, you download some kind of browser, which, like you mentioned, runs a website. So does this browser support WebGL2 or not, thats the real question here.

Comment: The games don't run on the phone, but on the "big screen" (laptop, PC, AndroidTV). For the controllers: you do not need to download the AirConsole app to play. You can use any common mobile browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari), consequently your games should work in all of those. For the app: Android uses Android System WebView (mainly based on Chromium) and iOS Safari WKWebView. Hope that clarifies things.